# How to create folder on Elastic Beanstalk server to install LetsEncrypt SSL certificate with AcmePHP

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lets-encrypt

I have a site running on an Elastic Beanstalk single instance server and want to add automated SSL certificate generation from LetsEncrypt using the AcmePHP library.

The library tries to store the certificates in `~/.acmephp`, which the server responds to with an error

```
Failed to create "/home/webapp/.acmephp": mkdir(): Permission denied.
```

The acmephp library doesn't have an option to change the path built in, and rather than fork and recompile the script, I'd like to be able to store the files in the default directory.

Does anyone know how I can give the app permission to create this directory, outside of the web root, or how I can make the server create it automatically and have it be available to the app?

Comment: Which client is this? There are a number of acme clients for php. Is it: https://github.com/kouk1/php-acme-client

Answer (score 0):

It looks like since it's being ran by the **webapp** user, when acmePHP is trying to store the certificate under that user's home directory it fails because that directory doesn't exist (afaik the webapp user only runs httpd and it definitely doesn't have a home directory).

A very dirty workaround could be manually creating that file and folder in the . ebextensions folder in your project.The file would be `.ebextensions/create_home.config` and it would contain something like this:

```
files:
  "/tmp/create-home.sh" :
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      mkdir -p /home/webapp
      chown webapp:webapp -R /home/webapp

commands:
  01_create:
    command: "/tmp/create-home.sh"
```

That script is ran by the **root** user, and afterwards it changes ownership of the `/home/webapp` folder to the **webapp** user and group respectively. Hope it helps